# Network-wide Help Center bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

I posted it on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345280/4751173) as well, but in any case: there's a network-wide bug affected all sites' Help Centers. E.g. this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic shows long-deleted Stack Overflow content [only Google can find](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22They%27re+used+a+lot+in+terrain+modelling.%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=LyvDWM_cK6bH8AfPwa6YDg):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> a "reticulated spline" is a valid geometrical entity. They're used a lot in terrain modelling. Because you can get non-reticulated splines, someone wiseguy obviously thought it good to start reticulating them.

Comment: We are aware and are in the process of fixing.

Comment: Reporting as fixed on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @KazWolfe - it really isn't. Getting there in a few minutes.

Comment: @Oded, well, I'm seeing it as normal on AU right now with others confirming, so...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be resolved. Details [on this meta.stackoverflow.com post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345280/what-if-i-see-someone-doing-something-bad/345281).

Comment: [This one](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is still broken. Maybe it was changed during the bug, it’s some weird case of caching, or one of the Vegetarianism mods is having a joke on us.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I made no changes to this page at all from my side. That's weird. :| Only change was made by another mod on Thursday, before the issue.

Comment: I don't know whether it's related to this bug, but [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) appears to be outdated as well. It's very confusing and aggravating for new users (and even fairly seasoned ones it seems) to be looking for reasons why their question/answer was downvoted and how they can be a better member of the community, only to find out that the advice given to them on **an official channel for such things** was completely wrong! Please fix this!!

Answer (score 6):

A fix is being rolled out as we speak.

I will let Nicks' answer stand by itself:

> [image: oh dear]

Comment: Meh - I wanted to blame it on Chrome, (it usually is).